# Categories of diagrams under the yoneda embedding

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be an arbitrary (locally small) category; $J$ a small category. I denote by $C^J = [J,C]$ the category of diagrams of shape $J$ in $C$ and by $\hat C = [C^{\mathrm{op}},(set)]$ the functor category such that $\mathbf h:C\to\hat C$ is the Yoneda embedding.

Clearly there is a functor $\mathbf c : C^J \to (\hat{C})^J$ by sending $F:J\to C$ to $\mathbf h\circ F : J\to \hat C$. *Question*: does the Yoneda embedding $\mathbf y : C^J \to \widehat{C^J}$ factor over $\mathbf c$?

Moreover, I am interested in any interesting properties that $\hat C^J$ may have. My main motivation is that $\hat C^J$ intuitively feels to me more like the correct analogon of the Yoneda embedding for categories of diagrams but I don't really understand why I feel that way about it.

Notes:

- There is a functor $\mathbf d: (\hat C)^J\to \widehat{C^J}$ which sends a functor $F:J\to \hat C$ to $\mathbf d(F)$ defined by $\mathbf d(F)(G:J\to C) = \hom(\mathbf h\circ G,F)$. But I don't see if and why $\mathbf d\circ\mathbf c = \mathbf y$.
- If $J$ is trivial (one object, one arrow) then $\mathbf d$ is an equivalence and $\mathbf c$ is essentially the yoneda embedding.
- Presumably one could ask more general questions about comparing $[X,[Y^{\mathrm{op}},Z]]$ with $[[X,Y]^{\mathrm{op}},Z]$ (with here $X=J$, $Y=C$, $Z=(set)$) but I'm not sure if that would do me any good.
- References studying in particular categories of diagrams $C^J$, the corresponding slice categories $((C^J)/D)$ (with $D:J\to C$ a particular diagram) an how they behave under the yoneda embedding are also very much appreciated.

Comment: To your first question: you have that $d(c(F))(G) = \mathrm{Nat}(h ∘ G, h ∘ F)$, while $y(F)(G) = \mathrm{Nat}(G, F)$. These sets cannot coincide, but since $h$ is fully faithful, they are isomorphic.

Comment: @user54748 Thanks! I realised yesterday that that part of my question was perhaps a bit silly. Feel free to post it as an answer though. Maybe my general question whether there is a theoretical justification that $\hat C^J$ is a suitable alternative for $\widehat{C^J}$ in some contexts is just a bit too broad.

Comment: I still think the question is an interesting one. Note also that the functor $c$ has a cocontinuous codomain, so at least for $C$ small it extends through the yoneda embedding $y$ to the functor $\hat c$ going in the direction opposite of $d$. Furthermore, $\hat c ∘ d ≅ \mathrm{Lan}_c c$ and that's $≅ \mathrm{Id}$ if $c = h^J$ is dense, but I'm not sure how to prove that in general.

Comment: @user54748 That sounds very useful! Unfortunately it is quite a bit out of my comfort zone so it took me a while to figure out your comment. So: every $X\in\hat{C^J}$ can be obtained as $X = \mathrm{colim}(D\to C^J\overset{y}\to\hat{C^J})$  for some category $D$ (apparently denoted $D=\int_C X$), and because $\hat C$ is cocomplete, so is $\hat C^J$ so you define $\hat c(X) = \mathrm{colim}(D\to C^J\overset{c}\to\hat{C}^J)$. And the problem with $C$ large is that $D$ may be large and $\hat C^J$ may not admit *arbitrary* colimits. Is all that correct? (I'm still chewing on the last sentence!)

Comment: Yes, this is the universal property of the Yoneda embedding, characterizing it as the free cocompletion. I don't know if and in what shape it holds for large categories, hence the restriction I mentioned.